# How can I return the location of http created resource along with a response status message in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, http, post, jax-rs

I'm working on a web service that works as follows:
[image]

1. The client sends a POST request to the REST server with some parameters.
2. The REST server handles the request, inserts the data to a table, creating a 
   new row with an ID.
3. The REST server then sends a request to the FileServer for uploadlink and the 
   FileServer returns the uploadLink to the REST server.
4. Finally, the REST server returns the location of the newly created resource 
   with ID, from step 2, to the client.

This is the POST handler:

```
@POST
public Response postFilesByCustomerId(AbstractPrincipal user, Attachment attachment) {
    Integer id = new AttachmentService(user).createNew(attachment);
    String uploadLink = FileServer.getUploadLinkForFile(user.getDB(), attachment.getUuid(), attachment.getFileName());
    return Response.created(LinkBuilder.getUriFromResource(this.getClass(), id)).build();
}
```

When I send POST request from the client, I get this response:
[image]

My question is, How can I include the uploadLink in the response? I'd really appreciate any suggestion or advice, java noob here.

Comment: Well, you basically have only 3 options: 1) include the `uploadlink` as a parameter of the `Location` url itself, eg: `Location: .../attachments/1?uploadlink=...`; 2) add a custom `X-...` header to the response, eg `X-UploadLink: ...`; 3) put the `uploadlink` in the payload of the response body. Either way, the client will need to know where to look for the uploadlink, so make sure you document that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I include the `uploadLink` in the response?

If you intend to send the URI in the **payload of the response**, you can use the following:

```
URI uri = LinkBuilder.getUriFromResource(this.getClass(), id);
return Response.created(uri).entity(uploadLink).build();
```

If you want to add a `Link` header, try the following:

```
return Response.created(uri).link(uploadLink, "upload").build();
```